# How to link ncurses.h library in CMakeLists.txt?

Tags: roscpp, ubuntu, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am currently attempting to repackage a C++ device driver into a ROS node that will accomplish the same thing.  However, the project is dependent on the ncurses library, and I am apparently not correctly linking the library, because I am getting a bunch of undefined reference errors to functions that, in the code are comment-labeled as coming from the ncurses library.  How do I properly link this library in my CMakeLists file?  This is what I have right now, but its not working:

```
add_executable(steering_keyboard_node src/steering_keyboard_node.cpp include/steeringKeyboard/workmanComm.cpp include/steeringKeyboard/workmanParams.cpp include/steeringKeyboard/ /usr/include/ncurses.h /usr/include/curses.h)
target_link_libraries(steering_keyboard_node ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187891/how-to-link-ncurses.h-library-in-cmakelists.txt?/) by [mysteriousmonkey29](https://answers.ros.org/users/9531/mysteriousmonkey29/) on ROS Answers with karma: 170 on 2014-07-25

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-07-26**:
Please show the errors you are getting and provide enough information on how to reproduce the problem. . Otherwise we have to guess what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Some time ago i has the same problem, but on ros fuerte version with rosbuild, maybe the solution still working
my solution consist on add:
`<rosdep name="ncurses++"/>` to the manifest
and on the CMakeLists something like that

```
find_package( PkgConfig REQUIRED )
pkg_check_modules ( ncurses++ REQUIRED ncurses++ )

rosbuild_add_executable(vant    
    src/....cpp
    src/....cpp
)
rosbuild_genmsg ()

target_link_libraries ( vant ${ncurses++_LIBRARIES})
```

sorry for my english.

---

Originally posted by [vitor.ecomp](https://answers.ros.org/users/19855/vitor.ecomp/) with karma: 16 on 2014-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-07-26**:
Note that these instructions are for rosbuild. For cakin, change  to `<build_depend>ncurses++</build_depend>` and `rosbuild_add_executable` to `add_executable`

**Comment by [mysteriousmonkey29](https://answers.ros.org/users/9531/mysteriousmonkey29/) on 2014-07-28**:
Thanks guys, adding build and run depend to my package.xml:

<build_depend>ncurses++</build_depend>
<run_depend>ncurses++</run_depend>
braries
and adding ${ncurses++_LIBRARIES} into my CMakeLists target_link_libraries line solved the problem.